# 'canvas.getContext' undefined, is not a function in AR Spark

Tags: augmented-reality, spark-ar-studio

I'm new with AR Spark and I saw that you can write scripts. I'm trying to write a script in pure js and I get the error about "'canvas.getContext' undefined" on canvas.

Code snippet :

```
    var sceneBase = Scene.root.child('Device').child('Camera').child('Focal Distance');
    var canvas = sceneBase.child('canvas0');
    var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
```

I have looked at the documentation but couldn't find anything about it.
Probably AR Spark doesn't support it but I'm just wondering.

Comment: You originally had `getContex' in the title, but 'getContext' in the code; I've made them self-consistent.  If you are missing the final t, that might explain your problem.  You might also want to explain why you think there should be a 'getContext' function given that you can't find it documented.

Answer (score 0):

That is easy, getContext() is not a member of canvas object, because you don't have a webpage.